# How to customize sikuli x ide?

Tags: sikuli-ide

I want to customize Sikuli x IDE. Like changing the title in title bar. I found the code on gitHub for Sikuli IDE but cant make out which line refers to the title. And how to run that in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what specifics you want to change on the IDE, but you mention running it in Eclipse. So if you prefer the Eclipse layout, you can code SikuliX projects from Eclipse directly and skip needing to modify the Sikuli IDE.

1. Get PyDev from Eclipse Plug-ins/Marketplace
2. Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Jython
3. Click "New..." button and add your jython.jar and click OK
4. The System Path window there will be populated and if it does not include sikulixapi.jar, click New Jar/Zips and add that as well.
5. Apply/OK
6. Repeat for Python interpreter as well

You will lose the ability to see images in the project.sikuli folder within the IDE (as far as I know) as well as to take snapshots or define regions using the IDE buttons. However, if you were looking to customize your own IDE, those features may be out of scope for your application anyway.

Comment: Can you explain it more elaborately? I created a java project and added  PyDev as well as Jython interpreter. For Python interpreter, i dont have python.jar and how to proceed after that. How do i get my Sikuli IDE running from Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I think I may have misread your question. I was giving directions for writing sikuli scripts in eclipse. It instead seems you wanted to open the Sikuli code in Eclipse. That I am not sure about.